# Insert from select or update from select with commit every 1M records

Tags: database, oracle

I've already seen a dozen such questions but most of them get answers that doesn't apply to my case.

First off - the database is am trying to get the data from has a very slow network and is connected to using VPN.

I am accessing it through a database link.

I have full write/read access on my schema tables but I don't have DBA rights so I can't create dumps and I don't have grants for creation new tables etc.

I've been trying to get the database locally and all is well except for one table.

It has 6.5 million records and 16 columns.
There was no problem getting 14 of them but the remaining two are Clobs with huge XML in them.

The data transfer is so slow it is painful.

I tried 
insert based on select
insert all 14 then update the other 2
create table as
insert based on select conditional so I get only so many records and manually commit

The issue is mainly that the connection is lost before the transaction finishes (or power loss or VPN drops or random error etc) and all the GBs that have been downloaded are discarded.

As I said I tried putting conditionals so I get a few records but even this is a bit random and requires focus from me.
Something like :

```
Insert into TableA 
Select * from TableA@DB_RemoteDB1 
WHERE CREATION_DATE BETWEEN to_date('01-Jan-2016') AND to_date('31-DEC-2016')
```

Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. Just after a few GBs Toad is stuck running but when I look at its throughput it is 0KB/s or a few Bytes/s.

What I am looking for is a loop or a cursor that can be used to get maybe 100000 or a 1000000 at a time - commit it then go for the rest until it is done.

This is a one time operation that I am doing as we need the data locally for testing - so I don't care if it is inefficient as long as the data is brought in in chunks and a commit saves me from retrieving it again.

I can count already about 15GBs of failed downloads I've done over the last 3 days and my local table still has 0 records as all my attempts have failed.

Server: Oracle 11g

Local: Oracle 11g

Attempted Clients: Toad/Sql Dev/dbForge Studio

Thanks.

Comment: Try dynamic sql with single day increments. So you have insert statement for one day's data and commit after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
begin
  loop
    insert into tablea
    select * from tablea@DB_RemoteDB1 a_remote
    where not exists (select null from tablea where id = a_remote.id)
    and rownum <= 100000; -- or whatever number makes sense for you

    exit when sql%rowcount = 0;

    commit;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This assumes that there is a primary/unique key you can use to check if a row int he remote table already exists in the local one - in this example I've used a vague `ID` column, but replace that with your actual key column(s).

For each iteration of the loop it will identify rows in the remote table which do not exist in the local table - which may be slow, but you've said performance isn't a priority here - and then, via `rownum`, limit the number of rows being inserted to a manageable subset.

The loop then terminates when no rows are inserted, which means there are no rows left in the remote table that don't exist locally.

This should be restartable, due to the commit and `where not exists` check. This isn't usually a good approach - as it kind of breaks normal transaction handling - but as a one off and with your network issues/constraints it may be necessary.

---

Toad is right, using bulk collect would be (probably significantly) faster **in general** as the query isn't repeated each time around the loop:

```
declare
  cursor l_cur is
    select * from tablea@dblink3 a_remote
    where not exists (select null from tablea where id = a_remote.id);
  type t_tab is table of l_cur%rowtype;
  l_tab t_tab;
begin
  open l_cur;
  loop
    fetch l_cur bulk collect into l_tab limit 100000;

    forall i in 1..l_tab.count
      insert into tablea values l_tab(i);

    commit;

    exit when l_cur%notfound;
  end loop;
  close l_cur;
end;
/
```

This time you would change the `limit 100000` to whatever number you think sensible. There is a trade-off here though, as the PL/SQL table will consume memory, so you may need to experiment a bit to pick that value - you could get errors or affect other users if it's too high. Lower is less of a problem here, except the bulk inserts become slightly less efficient.

**But** because you have a CLOB column (holding your XML) this won't work for you, as @BobC pointed out; the `insert ... select` [is supported over a DB link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_working.htm#ADLOB2010), but the collection version will get an error from the fetch:

> ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
>   ORA-06512: at line 10
>   22992. 00000 -  "cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables"
>   *Cause:    A remote LOB column cannot be referenced.
>   *Action:   Remove references to LOBs in remote tables.

Comment: I've done similar to this many times across DB's.  Ideally, as mentioned, the tables have keys to be compared, but I've used MINUS instead of NOT EXISTS to get the missing keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex - I'll test this and get back to you

Comment: This is working great so far - Toad is suggesting converting it to BULKCOLLECT and FORALL..Any ideas how/why that would be better?

Comment: @AngelicCore - Toad is right, but how much difference it actually makes would need to be tested. For a one-off process it might not matter, but yes, bulk collect and forall is better even here. I've added the code for that approach to my answer.

Comment: @AngelicCore. This works? I did not think you could fetch a CLOB via a database link...?

Comment: @BobC - yes it works. This is the first of the [three ways that remote LOBs are supported](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_working.htm#ADLOB2010). (Not necessarily a good idea though; data pump would probably be preferable still.)

Comment: @AlexPoole. I get this:   select * from emp_resume@mylink
SQL> /
ERROR:
ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables

Comment: @BobC - Ah, you're right, the first version works (because `insert ... select` is supported), the second one doesn't. I'll update to mention that, thanks. When I saw the OP's comment and went back to add the bulk version, I didn't reread the question and had forgotten is mentioned a CLOB, so I didn't retest that.

Comment: Exactly - as Alex pointed out - you can't select clobs directly through DBLinks but you can insert select.